# Crystal Report inserts a blank page after a report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

Everything I have found so far has not worked for me.
I have a Crystal Report with header, details and footer. The details section is a text that occupies two pages. In the report preview everything is fine. If I export the report to pdf, an empty page is inserted at the end. I tried to modify the margins and the settings of the sections but without getting anything.
A very strange thing is that the blank page shows the writing: Pages 3 of 2 (absurd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of useless attempts, I solved by printing only the full pages.

Comment: Please check if new page after or new page before check is not ON in section expert.

Answer (score 1):

Some times just if a row(design rows) exeed the margin of the page you will get a blank page, try to check if this is happening.

Comment: I tried all the ways, I reduced the detail section to half the page and I also tried to suppress the page header and foot, but nothing changed. Report preview; everything ok, press: a blank page at the bottom.

Comment: OK, so you can colorize all the section, if possible and find wich one is causing the problem. Also check the status of the Keep together flag in the section expert

Answer (score 0):

Make sure report content isn't too close to (or go beyond) the right page margin.